# Meaning of two continuous the-clauses

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

Would you grammatically explain whats the purpose of these two "the-clauses", clear the meaning behind them, and the relation they have to their surrounding words please:

> The style links it to Humphrey, a society painter who was **the *kind of professional* the wealthy Austen family *would hire***. Humphrey was active in the late 1785s and early 1795s, exactly the period when ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a reduced clause:

... who was the kind of professional (that) the wealthy Austen family would hire

the sort of music the baby likes to hear

the type of glue the shoemaker uses on the sole